# Sequelize-Typescript typeof model

Tags: typescript, sequelize-typescript

I'm trying to create a base crud service that takes a Sequelize model and creates all basic APIs for it so what I have done it this:

```js
export class RepositoryService<T extends Model<T>> {
  constructor(protected model: typeof Model) {
  }
  public async getMany(
    query: RequestParamsParsed = {},
    options: RestfulOptions = {},
  ): Promise<T[]> {
    return this.model.findAll();
  }
}
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
The 'this' context of type 'typeof Model' is not assignable to method's 'this' of type 'new () => Model<Model<any>>'.
  Cannot assign an abstract constructor type to a non-abstract constructor type.
```

this is because of this line in the `seqeulize-typescript` package:

```
static findAll<T extends Model<T>>(this: (new () => T), options?: IFindOptions<T>): Promise<T[]>;
```

I'm relatively new to `Typescript` so if anyone can tell me what's the meaning of `this: (new () => T)` in the `findAll` function and how can I work this out.

Comment: `arg: (new () => T)` means that arg is not instance of type `T` like in `(arg: T)`. arg is class T. Also you can use this syntax for that `(arg: { new (...args): T })`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seemed to be in this line

```
constructor(protected model: typeof Model) {}
```

The `Model` I was setting the model type to is imported from `sequelize-typescript` while I should use the original model exported from `sequelize` itself.

The whole code is like this:

```js
import { Model as OriginalModel } from 'sequelize';
import { Model } from 'sequelize-typescript';
export class RepositoryService<T extends Model<T>> {
  constructor(protected model: typeof OriginalModel) {
  }
  public async getMany(
    query: RequestParamsParsed = {},
    options: RestfulOptions = {},
  ): Promise<T[]> {
    return this.model.findAll();
  }
}
```

Comment: Better solution from @Adrian below.

Answer (score 5):

Also encountered this error while working with the `sequelize-typescript` library.

You could first define these helper types:

```
import { Model } from "sequelize-typescript";

// Type `ModelType` would basically wrap & satisfy the 'this' context of any sequelize helper methods
type Constructor<T> = new (...args: any[]) => T;
type ModelType<T extends Model<T>> = Constructor<T> & typeof Model;
```

Then, use it with your code:

```
export class RepositoryService<T extends Model<T>> {
  constructor(protected model: ModelType<T>) {}

  public async getMany(
    query: RequestParamsParsed = {},
    options: RestfulOptions = {},
  ): Promise<T[]> {
    return this.model.findAll();
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Using `"sequelize-typescript": "2.1.0"` you can use `ModelCtor` provided by the module eg.

```js
import { Model, ModelCtor } from 'sequelize-typescript';

export class RepositoryService<T extends Model<T>> {
  constructor(protected model: ModelCtor<T>) {}

  public async getMany(
    query: RequestParamsParsed = {}, 
    options: RestfulOptions = {}
): Promise<T[]> {
    return this.model.findAll();
  }
}
```

The `ModelCtor` type is:

```js
export declare type Repository<M> = (new () => M) & NonAbstract<typeof Model>;

export declare type ModelCtor<M extends Model = Model> = Repository<M>;
```